# how to render rendering data node, ejs and express?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

```
function (err,result,body) {
    //console.log(typeof body);
    var body = JSON.parse(body);
    //console.log(body);
    var allusers = new Array();
    allusers.push(body);
 }
```

in body variable i have json object which i want to render on contact.ejs page

body contain the below data:

```
{
    "allUsers": [{
        "id": "35",
        "isDevice": "true",
        "username": "IPG06",
        "email": "ldm@email.com",
        "imgLastUpdate": "",
        "name": "[ Big Drum ]",
        "surname": "",
        "jobPositionName": "[ LINEA DE PRODUCCION ]",
        "jobPositionID": "35",
        "identifier": "IPG06"
    }, {
        "id": "37",
        "isDevice": "true",
        "username": "IPG08",
        "email": "ldm@email.com",
        "imgLastUpdate": "",
        "name": "[ Pasto 1 ]",
        "surname": "",
        "jobPositionName": "[ LINEA DE PRODUCCION ]",
        "jobPositionID": "35",
        "identifier": "IPG08"
    }]
}
```

i need to send the below to contact.ejs but without this `{"allUsers":`
its should be start with

```
[{
    "id": "35",
    "isDevice": "true",
    "username": "IPG06",
    "email": "ldm@email.com",
    "imgLastUpdate": "",
    "name": "[ Big Drum ]",
    "surname": "",
    "jobPositionName": "[ LINEA DE PRODUCCION ]",
    "jobPositionID": "35",
    "identifier": "IPG06"
 }, {
    "id": "37",
    "isDevice": "true",
    "username": "IPG08",
    "email": "ldm@email.com",
    "imgLastUpdate": "",
    "name": "[ Pasto 1 ]",
    "surname": "",
    "jobPositionName": "[ LINEA DE PRODUCCION ]",
    "jobPositionID": "35",
    "identifier": "IPG08"
 }]


res.render('pages/contacts',{
    ids:contacts_array,
    allusers:allusers
});
```

Comment: Can you post some more code related to the data you want to send back?  You reference "body" twice here (both as the data being added to the array and as the object that you want to send to contact.ejs).  How do you reference the JSON object you printed out in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple :
You have **body** variable that has property 'allUsers' with value as array of ojects.

So, 'body.allUsers' is all you need to send in response.

Your code would be like :

```
res.render('pages/contacts',{
    ids:contacts_array,
    allusers:body.allUsers // This will send array of objects.
});
```